# Linux command to generate new GUID?

Tags: linux, guid

Sometimes in bash scripting, i need to generate new `GUID(Global Unique Identifier)`.

I already done that by a simple python script that generates a new guid: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-in-python)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import uuid
print str(uuid.uuid1())
```

But i need to copy this script into any new system that i works on.

**My question is**: can anybody introduce a command or package that contains similar command ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command line GUID for Unix and Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569858/command-line-guid-for-unix-and-windows)

Comment: random uuid? pseudo-random from a given seed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming you don't have `uuidgen`, you don't need a script:

```
$ python -c 'import uuid; print(str(uuid.uuid4()))'
b7fedc9e-7f96-11e3-b431-f0def1223c18
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't seem to be quite random: only the 8 first characters change on every call.

Answer (score 38):

You can use command `uuidgen`. Simply executing `uuidgen` will give you time-based UUID:

```
$ uuidgen
18b6f21d-86d0-486e-a2d8-09871e97714e
```

Comment: If you mean uuidgen for Linux, be careful, on Ubuntu 20.04, it is default to generate as random-based UUID. It mentions in man page `By default uuidgen will generate a random-based UUID if a high-quality random number  generator  is  present. Otherwise,  it  will choose  a  time-based  UUID.`

Comment: So let's help people to ensure they avoid that pitfall! `uuidgen -h` for help shows that `uuidgen -r` will enforce generating a random UUID. I don't know if all distros' versions default to time-based, but including `-r` should ensure randomness.

Answer (score 9):

```sh
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6):

Since you wanted a *random* UUID, you want to use Type 4 instead of Type 1:

```
python -c 'import uuid; print str(uuid.uuid4())'
```

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) explains the different types of UUIDs. You want "Type 4 (Random)".

I wrote a little Bash function using Python to generate an arbitrary number of Type 4 UUIDs in bulk:

```
# uuid [count]
#
# Generate type 4 (random) UUID, or [count] type 4 UUIDs.
function uuid()
{
    local count=1
    if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; then
        if [[ "$1" =~ [^0-9] ]]; then
            echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME [count]" >&2
            return 1
        fi

        count="$1"
    fi

    python -c 'import uuid; print("\n".join([str(uuid.uuid4()).upper() for x in range('"$count"')]))'
}
```

If you prefer lowercase, change:

```
python -c 'import uuid; print("\n".join([str(uuid.uuid4()).upper() for x in range('"$count"')]))'
```

To:

```
python -c 'import uuid; print("\n".join([str(uuid.uuid4()) for x in range('"$count"')]))'
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3, no cast to `str` is required:

```
python -c 'import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to generate a pseudo-random string with some dashes at locations 8, 12, 16, and 20, you can use `apg`.

```
apg -a 1 -M nl -m32 -n 1 -E ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | \
    sed -r -e 's/^.{20}/&-/' | sed -r -e 's/^.{16}/&-/' | \
    sed -r -e 's/^.{12}/&-/' | sed -r -e 's/^.{8}/&-/'
```

The `apg` clause generates 32 symbols from `[0-9a-f]` (lower-case). The series of `sed` commands add the `-` tokens and can very likely be shortened.

Note that often an UUID has a particular format:

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Here `M` and `N` fields encode the version/format of the UUID.